# PHP URL masking in a home-grown MVC framework

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a MVC app in PHP and it's working well, but I want to have a feature where I can mask URLs, for example I have this URL `localhost:1900/index/register` which calls from the `index.php` controller the method `register`.

However, I only want to show `localhost:1900/register` as URL and still do the same thing, call from `index.php` the `register` method, any ideas on how can I obtain that? I am using Apache with htaccess.

This is the content of htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On


php_flag display_errors on
php_value short_open_tag 1
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: are you using apache?

Comment: yes, I am using apache with htaccess.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate how routing works at the moment - what is the contents of your htaccess file? Does this connect with a front controller to run an appropriate controller in 'index/register' in some way?

Comment: What is the framework you use? Does it your own?

Comment: Yes, it's my framework, I created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to re-write that in your .htccess on Apache, try:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index/$1/ [L,QSA]`

to rewrite all to index, or:

`RewriteRule ^register$ /index/register/ [L,QSA]`

to rewrite only register

Comment: @Cioroianu: so you know, if you say "it's not working" but do not offer any further details, readers may find it hard to know what to suggest next. It is a good idea to take answers as suggested points for further research, rather than precise things to type in verbatim. So, here, find out _why_ this does not work for you. Consider turning on mod_rewrite logging to see what is going on under the hood, and be willing to debug this.

Comment: As @halfer said, you may have to play around a bit. Also, you can use a tool such as [http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) to test your .htaccess rules against a URL

Comment: It worked with the second rule, I was miss typing something, thank you Daryll :)

Comment: Daryll, if I put `RewriteRule ^register$ /index/register/ [L,QSA]` in my .htaccess file before `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` the second `RewriteRule` won't get executed, but I want both rules to get executed, how can I do that ?

Comment: Hi @CioroianuDenis If you remove the L from the flags at the end of the first `RewriteRule` the second will also be executed. The L flag is for last, so if that rule matches, it won't process any more. You can read about it at: [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you using? in apache, you can enable mod_rewrite and set rewrite rules in .htaccess. In IIS you must install IIS Url Rewrite extension and then set the rules almost the same way as for PHP.

here's a small example from a web.config file I made some time ago:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Riscrivi URL index" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).php" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/Pages/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I used this file in a CodeIgniter installation, hiding "index.php" from the client point of view, and dinamically adding it to urls ppointed by the client to match correct controller methods

Comment: Is the bulk of this answer for IIS? If so, good answer, but it's for the wrong question `:)`. If the web server (or anything else) is in doubt, it's worth confirming this first.

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote the answer you still hadn't published details about apache. Feel free to delete it

Comment: It's not my question `:)`, and afaik you request to delete, not me.